# I copied a Windows VM from Mac VMWare to Windows VMWare Player. It runs, but very slowly

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player, vmware-fusion

I copied a Windows XP VM that I've been using on my Mac (VMWare Fusion)to a Windows 7 machine that has VMWare Player installed. I was quite pleased when it started up and appeared to work, but when I actually tried to use it, I noticed it runs very slowly. Unusably so. It takes about 10 minutes, for example, for a Visual Studio 2010 project to open (with VS 2010 running in the VM).

Is this supposed to work? Is there any way to fix this VM to get it to run well under Windows VMWare Player?

Answer (score 1):

- Check VMware tools version.  Replacewith one from win 7?
- Does the vm have a snapshot? Remove it.
- Is it any quicker if you boot windows in the VM in rescue mode?
- Try booting from a Linux CD in the VM. Is that
  quicker? YES

UPDATE:

- Try cutting the amount of memory to 512Mb for the VM.

Comment: I installed a Ubuntu 10.10 under VMWare player on that machine and it's very fast. The machine (which has 48 GB of Memory and 12 hyperthreaded cores) barely cracks 5% CPU usage and 5GB of memory use, so I'm not hitting on machine limits.)  I'll check to see if there's a "snapshot"...I presume that would be a file in the directory that contains the files which comprise the VM?